# How do I convert a base64 exported public key into something I can use in php?

Tags: php, swift, pki

I am able to export a public key generated in iOS and convert it to base64:

```
var dataPtr:Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
let query: [String:AnyObject] = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: "com.example.site.public",
    kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue
]
let qResult = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &dataPtr)

// error handling with `qResult` ...

let publicKeyData = dataPtr!.takeRetainedValue() as NSData

// convert to Base64 string
let base64PublicKey = publicKeyData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
```

I also was able to send it to my LAMP server. Now I'm trying to figure out how to use it as a public key over there.

I tried:

```
$keydata = base64decode($_GET['base64PublicKey']);
$res = gnupg_init();
$info = gnupg_import($res,$keydata);
print_r($info);
```

Is this the right direction? I'm aware that the size of the data is 270, [not the same as block size of the key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14491/why-is-a-2048-bit-public-rsa-key-represented-by-540-hexadecimal-characters-in-x). I'm somewhat new to PKI, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The certificate is in DER-encoded X.509 format ?

Comment: I think so, but I am not completely sure. This seems to indicate so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840005/how-to-find-out-the-modulus-and-exponent-of-rsa-public-key-on-iphone-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

If your pub key is X.509 conformant you can parse with PHP like this:

```
$keydata = base64decode($_GET['base64PublicKey']);
$info = openssl_x509_parse($keydata,true);
print_r($info);
```

PHP includes a library for [OpenSSl and X.509](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help! It turns out that `publicKeyData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)` is returning non-base64 characters -- specifically forward slashes and spaces, so base64_decode() is returning false. Once I get past that I'll be able to test your code.